# Issue with SSL Pining using Dio Flutter my certificate is wildcard certificate

Tags: android, ios, flutter, ssl, dio

In flutter i am trying to implement SSL Pinning using dio: ^4.0.4 but every time I am getting this error

> HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
> CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer
> certificate(handshake.cc:393))

```
       String pem = "";

  late ByteData _byteData;

Future<ByteData> loadAsset() async {
    String _part = BUILD_ENV == 0 ? "dev" : BUILD_ENV == 1 ? "stage" : BUILD_ENV == 3 ? "test" : "live";
    return await rootBundle.load('assets/certificate/$_part/sslCertificate.pem');}

  Future<String> loadPem() async {
    String _part = BUILD_ENV == 0 ? "dev" : BUILD_ENV == 1 ? "stage" : BUILD_ENV == 3 ? "test" : "live";
    return rootBundle.loadString('assets/certificate/$_part/sslCertificate.pem');
  }
```

method 1:

```
(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate = (client) {
  SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContext();
  securityContext.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(_byteData.buffer.asUint8List());
  HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient(context: securityContext);
  return httpClient;
};
```

method 2:

```
(dio.httpClientAdapter as DefaultHttpClientAdapter).onHttpClientCreate  = (client) {
  debugPrint("badCertificateCallback :: xx");
  client.badCertificateCallback=(X509Certificate cert, String host, int port){
    debugPrint("badCertificateCallback :: yy ::${cert.pem}");
    if(cert.pem==pem){ // Verify the certificate
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
  return client;
};
```

method 1 keeps giving handshake error (described above)

method 2 (badCertificateCallback :: yy ::) line never get executed (this method never worked)

one more thing my certificate is wildcard certificate *.example.com
and my API base URL is api.example.com

can anyone help me to fix this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
String FINGERPRINT_DEV = '45 ED 46 4E 79 3D F6 A7 FD 5F 34 14 5B DF FD B6 B3 EE 7A C1 5C 3D E6 0A 21 45 C7 A1 87 C6 80 23';
  
String FINGERPRINT_STAGE = '45 22 D3 FD 31 15 74 DA FA 27 1C 88 61 C1 D3 7D A9 00 8C 3F E4 D0 86 1A 8B 45 04 17 68 25 0E E8';
  
String FINGERPRINT_TEST = '45 AE FB E8 E4 20 8C CD B4 9D EB 51 CD 1D 57 81 61 97 90 46 6F 26 B1 F1 0E BC 45 11 52 5C 1A D7';
  
String FINGERPRINT_LIVE = '5B 45 78 A0 96 AC 97 12 05 35 92 4B 25 FD AB 7E A1 42 B2 FE 12 BF AD 4C 45 5A C4 D0 BA 5A AB 14';



dio.interceptors.add(CertificatePinningInterceptor(allowedSHAFingerprints: [BUILD_ENV == 0 ? FINGERPRINT_DEV : BUILD_ENV == 1 ? FINGERPRINT_STAGE : BUILD_ENV == 3 ? FINGERPRINT_TEST : FINGERPRINT_LIVE]));
```

Comment: i solved this myself if this answer help someone plz upvote

Comment: Can you write how you solved it?